# cakephp search and paginate between date

Tags: php, search, cakephp-1.3, date-range

I'm trying to modify this code to implement a search in my application 
http://mrphp.com.au/code/search-forms-cakephp

the code work but I'm trying to add a filter by date

and this filter doesn't work...

this is my code

```
    if(isset($this->passedArgs['Search.data1']) ) {
    $data1=$this->passedArgs['Search.data1'];
    $this->log($data1,LOG_DEBUG);

    if(isset($this->passedArgs['Search.data2']) ) {
        $data2=$this->passedArgs['Search.data2'];
    }
        else {
        $data2=$this->passedArgs['Search.data1'];

    }

    $this->paginate['conditions'][] = array('Report.data BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($data1,$data2));
```

}

the url is like index/Search.data1:2011-05-19/Search.data2:2011-05-26

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your paginate conditions:

```
$this->paginate['Report']['conditions'] = array("Report.data BETWEEN '$data1' AND '$data2'");
```

That should work.